# How do you debug a mod_perl2 module without restarting?

Tags: perl, apache2, perl-module, httpd.conf, mod-perl2

Environment: Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) mod_apreq2-20051231/2.6.2-dev mod_perl/2.0.4-dev Perl/v5.10.0

Situation very similar to what's described in [this discussion list post](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/modperl/modperl/98854), except for being on win32.

I have this in httpd.conf:

```
PerlModule Apache2::Reload
PerlInitHandler Apache2::Reload
PerlSetVar ReloadAll Off
PerlSetVar ReloadModules "MyPackage::*"
```

...as well as only mod-perl script handling.

I have a script that uses a MyPackage module, and it's working.

I break the module, and reload the script.  The error is a helpful one, telling the line where I broke the module.

(If I reload again at this point, and it only tells me "Undefined subroutine &ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::Registry..." because it wasn't able to load the file the first time.  But either way the following behaviour still happens.)

I revert the break, and touch the script file too so it'll reload the module, and reload.  Now it says:

```
Attempt to reload MyPackage/Foo.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at E:/dev/test.pl line 4.
```

And even if I touch the script and the module, I cannot get it to reload correctly, except by restarting the web server.

Breaking just the script itself (as opposed to the module) works fine: proper errors and changing it back results in it working again upon reload.

After each of these things I restarted the web server before testing:

1. I've tried doing a trace, but the
   line that it continues to error out
   on is ModPerl/RegistryCooker.pm line
   204, which is just the line that
   eval{}s the whole script.
2. I've tried changing "use warnings
   FATAL => 'all'" to just "use
   warnings" in the script and the
   module.  Didn't make a difference.
3. I've tried disabling my custom
   $SIG{__DIE__} function.  Didn't
   make a difference.  (Well, only in
   where the error appeared, of course,
   but the errors generated were the
   same.)
4. Per the discussion link at the beginning, found that MaxRequestsPerChild has been 0 this whole time, and I tried ThreadsPerChild 1, but no difference.  I tried MaxRequestsPerChild to 1, which solves the weird behaviours of this question, but restarts the web server after every single request:

   ```
   Child 7072: Process exiting because it reached MaxRequestsPerChild. Signaling the parent to restart a new child process.
   Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
   ```

   This isn't a good solution, since I have a significant chunk of code that's run the first time a page is hit.
5. Also per the discussion, I run httpd as a service, so I added -X in the service parameters window and hit Start, and it was still trying to start a full three minutes later (usually starts within 3 seconds.)  Even got a timeout message.  Killed process via task manager and verified I couldn't hit the page from a web browser.  Started httpd -X from the command line.  Still the same behaviour as at the top of this question.  Also I found it odd that -X was not listed when I ran httpd -?.  Maybe it's not available on the win32 MPM?
6. In that thread, David notes:

   > My experience troubleshooting this
   >   kind of issue has indicated that its
   >   likely that the package that was
   >   unloaded deleted a value stored in the
   >   package space of the module reloaded
   >   (probably set at BEGIN block time)
   >   that the subsequent require did not
   >   restore.

   But this isn't true of my code.  The 'break the script' error I introduce is just adding an extra 'my $var' line above one that's already there, so that the second one will complain that it's already been declared.

Is there no way to work on mod_perl2 modules without having the web server restart after every reload (whether automatically, via MaxRequestsPerChild, or manually, as before)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the sub to the script you're calling it from, and put this code before the copy:

```
package MyPackage::Foo;
no warnings 'redefine';
```

When you're done making changes, move the sub back to the actual module.

Comment: You do have to restart after copying it back (sometimes!) but it's helpful until then, anyway.